# Run main process as child_process

Tags: node.js, child-process, electron

I am having troubles with getting `child_process` working with Atom Electron. First of all, I am using the pre-compiled binary app that you can download from Electron's website:

- I am using the usual pre-compiled binary on Mac OS X.
- In `myapp.app/Contents/Resources` I made a folder app as described.
- I added a brief `package.json` inside it, setting `index.js` as main script.

Now, if I add to `index.js` the following snippet:

```
'use strict';

var electron = require('electron');
var app = electron.app;

const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;

var mainWindow;

function createWindow () {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600});
  mainWindow.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/index.html');
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
  mainWindow.on('closed', function()
  {
    mainWindow = null;
  });
}

app.on('ready', createWindow);

app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin')
  {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on('activate', function () {
  if (mainWindow === null)
  {
    createWindow();
  }
});
```

(that is basically the example code to get things working) everything works fine. I get the window and I can get it to do basically anything.

Now, for reasons related to updates, I am in need to slightly change this paradigm. What I would need is to be able to perform several tasks from `index.js` **without any need to do any gui operation** (it should be some sort of daemon) and then to start some `child.js` script as a `child_process` from `index.js`. `child.js` should be able to open windows and all the rest.

So here was my naive try. I just cut and pasted the example snippet above in `child.js`, then edited `index.js` into the following:

```
var child_process = require('child_process');
var my_child = child_process.fork(__dirname + '/child.js');
```

Quite minimal, right? Hoped it would work, but it didn't. When I double click on my pretty app, nothing happens. I bet I am doing something wrong in a trivial way, but I wouldn't be able to tell what.

**Update 1** I moved this out of my package so that I could get `console.log`s. `child.js` dies with an error at `require('electron')`: it doesn't seem to be able to find it.

**Update 2**: I listed the environment variables in `child.js` and noticed a `ATOM_SHELL_INTERNAL_RUN_AS_NODE = 1`. I thought I should turn that to `0`, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

In Electron [`child_process.fork()`](https://github.com/atom/node/commit/19618c4f614915c908f469879849d08075b9508c) will spawn the child with the [`ATOM_SHELL_INTERNAL_RUN_AS_NODE`](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/v0.36.7/docs/api/environment-variables.md#electron_run_as_node) environment variable set, which means that no Chromium features will be available in the child process (so no Electron built-in modules), all you'll get is the vanilla Node runtime plus a patched `fs` that can read inside ASAR files. If you look at the code for `child_process.fork()` you'll see there's no way to override the value of `ATOM_SHELL_INTERNAL_RUN_AS_NODE`. If you can, use `child_process.spawn()` instead, failing that I guess you could try opening an issue and asking if the Electron team will be open to modifying the current behavior.

Comment: Should the spawned process be running in detached mode? It is important to me to make `index.js` and `child.js` talk to each other.

Comment: To be honest I'm not overly familiar with spawning of detached processes, though it seems like that would prevent the parent and child from communicating via stdio pipes. I'd suggest opening an issue to change `child_process.fork()` to respect the existing value of the `ATOM_SHELL_INTERNAL_RUN_AS_NODE` environment variable instead of always setting it.